Django simple JWT blacklist all tokens for user
I have created an application that uses JWT tokens for authenticating the back end.
I have also created a custom user model so I could add a few user permissions (can_create, can_publish). These values can be seen when decoding the JWT token, giving the frontend access.
I have allowed a user with superuser status to update user permissions of another user.
The problem i face, is that when a superuser updates permissions of another user, if that user is already logged in (ive stored the refresh token in the cookies), when the front end decodes the token, it shows the old values, and not the updated ones. Only once the user logs out and logs back in, receiving a new accessToken and refreshToken do the updated values show.
Is there a way make all current tokens of the user who got their permissions changed invalid, forcing the updateToken function on my front end to fail, resulting in them getting logged out?
I tried this
# Update user permisions
@api_view(["PUT"])
@permission_classes([IsOrganizationAdmin])
def update_user_permisions(request, userUUID):
    
    # check user exists
    user = User.objects.filter(uuid=userUUID).first()
    
    if user is None:
        return Response({"detail": "user does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    # check if organizations match
    if user.organization != request.user.organization:
        return Response({"detail": "Oranizations do not match"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    
    serializer = UserPermisionsSerializer(data=request.data, instance=user)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        # whipe all current tokens for that user
        for token in OutstandingToken.objects.filter(user=user):
                _, _ = BlacklistedToken.objects.get_or_create(token=token)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response({"detail": "error has occured"}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        

But the refresh token stored in the users cookies still seems to be valid?
Any insight would be appriciated

Were you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue?
